# Intellij Test Case not Exiting

Tags: intellij-idea, build.gradle, junit4, springjunit4classrunner

I am using **Intellij 2019.2** version. I have a project where we have **Java** and **Kotlin** used for source code. **Gradle** is used for compile and build. **JUnit 4** test cases have been added for Java code.

*Test cases for package, run fine and succeed, but the process does not stop.* This happens when I run the test case for entire package in any mode run/debug/with coverage. But if individual class or method test case is run then the process ends.

Comment: Does the issue occur when you run the test from the command line using Gradle? If it works fine via Gradle, but hangs in IntelliJ IDEA, please see if [changing the delegation option](https://i.imgur.com/AmWjMZR.png) helps. If it still occurs no matter what setting is used, please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I haven't checked command line.

Comment: Please check and report back.

Comment: looks like this was happening because of VPN issues. When running the tests, Intellij was building the code and not able to download the JARs. Intellij just hangs and does not even timeout with error. Once VPN was connected JARs were downloaded and tests cleared. Thanks for all the help ....